# how can i redirect to loop over multiple variables in django html

Tags: django, django-templates

i want to go for different page based on value of  i ,i know the syntax is incorrect but i need some suggestions for doing the same thing in an alternate way
i am new in stack overflow please forgive if my question is stupid

```
{% for document,i in details , flag reversed %}
<tr>
    {% if i %}
        <td><li><a href="{{ document.docfile.url}}">{{ document.docfile}}</a></li> </td>
    {%  else %}
        <td><li><a href="./{{ whole }}/{{ document.docfile}}">{{ document.docfile}}</a></li> </td>
    {% endif %}
    <td>{{ document.DateOfUpload}}</td>
    <td>{{ document.emailid}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

> here is views .py

```
def getAllFiles(request,project_name,wholepath):
    wholepath=str(wholepath)
    whole=[]
    whole=wholepath.split('/')
    w=len(whole)
    w=w-1
    whole=whole[w]
    wholepath= wholepath.replace('/', '\\')
    wholepath="./media/"+wholepath
    if wholepath:
         getallfiles=Document.objects.filter(parentdirectory=wholepath)
         print(getallfiles)
         flag=[]
         i=0
         for c  in getallfiles:
             i=i+1;
             st=(c.docfile)
             st=str(st)
             print(st,type(st))
             if os.path.isfile(st):
                flag.insert(i,"1")
             else:
                 flag.insert(i,"0")



         return render(request, 'FileView.html', {'details': getallfiles,'whole': whole, 'flag': flag}) 

    else:
        getallfiles=Document.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'AllUploads.html', {'details': getallfiles,'whole':whole})
```

> urls.py

```
  path('projectlist/<slug:project_name>/<path:wholepath>', views.getAllFiles),
```

if it is a file then the url should look something like ./media/filelocation
or else if it is a directory then it should add the previous path

Comment: Show your model(s) and view code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `zip_longest`

For example I have 3 lists:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

list1=[1,2,3]
 list2=['a','b','c']
 list2=[5,6,7] 

 list=list(zip_longest(list1,list2,list3))
for x,y,z in list:
 print(x,y,z)
```

output:

```
1 a 5
2 b 6
3 c 7
```

Comment: Hi sagar feel free to ask any question

Comment: but in my  case i have a list and an object

Comment: getallfiles is a queryset that is having object. Did you try to loop through it as I suggested

Comment: Got to know how to do it

Comment: ya did and it worked fine in views but at the  django templates the loop is not working    list =zip_longest(flag, getallfiles)
         for x, y in list:
             print(x, y)//(working fine)


         return render(request, 'FileView.html', {'details': list, 'whole': whole})                            {% for i,document in details  reversed %}// this loop in html  is not working